# IdentityServer3 - OAuth Flows, different approaches

Tags: javascript, api, backbone.js, oauth, identityserver3

I've built an application that is substantially a REST Web API. I would like to give to other developers the opportunity to invoke those APIs on behalf of the user. I decided to go on with OAuth authentication, basing my Authentication Service on IdentityServer3.
Right now I've succeeded in generating an Access Token for a third-party client using Authorization Flow.

What is not convincing me is how to handle my SPA that currently invokes my Web API using just cookie based authentication (+ anti-forgery token). This application in written in Javascript, based on Backbone. Substantially, what it does is just call my Web API and render results. I'm confused by the different grant flows, and I don't want to create security holes.

Solutions I've thought:

1. generate a token directly via Javascript. Which kind of flow should I use? How to handle token refresh?
2. generate a token from a backend server application and pass the generated token back to the SPA (obviously through an SSL channel). Is this somehow secure? If yes, which kind of flow should I use (I'd say Authorization Code Flow)? How to handle token refresh?

How would you handle this?

Thanks,

Marco

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an article that goes into an overview of which flow is right for which scenario: https://leastprivilege.com/2016/01/17/which-openid-connectoauth-2-o-flow-is-the-right-one/

Comment: Thanks! I've already stumbled upon that great article. If I understand correctly, the right usage would be the Implict Flow and let my Javascript SPA handle directly this access token.
Now the question is: isn't it "unsafe" to let the "browser" client handle directly the token? Thanks.

Comment: Depends on the API. But if you need calls from JS then you need to give the JS a token. Perhaps a different design is to have the JS call a first layer of API, which in turn calls a second layer of API. Of course, the second API needs its own access token, which is your next problem to solve.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Sounds like the Implicit Flow is the correct solution. I won't create a second layer of API. Thanks